# Cant understand some python tuple syntax

Tags: python, python-2.7, syntax, tuples

I started learning python today and found this very nice code visualization tool [pythontutor.com](http://pythontutor.com), the problem is that I still don't quite get some of the syntax on the example code.

```
def listSum(numbers):
    if not numbers:
        return 0
    else:
        (f, rest) = numbers
        return f + listSum(rest)

    myList = (1, (2, (3, None)))
    total = listSum(myList)
```

What does `(f, rest) = numbers` means?

Comment: That piece of demo code is truly horrid. I find it hard to imagine ever needing to form or parse a cons-style (a.k.a. LISP) in Python. I can't think of good use for that in LISP, but it's been a long time. The answers are fine, read them and forget you ever saw this bit of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's *tuple* **unpacking**.

There needs to be 2 items in the *tuple* when used in this way. More or less will result in an *exception*, as shown below.

```
>>> numbers = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
>>> (f, rest) = numbers
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack
>>> numbers = (1, 2)
>>> (f, rest) = numbers
>>> print f
1
>>> print rest
2
>>> numbers = (1)
>>> (f, rest) = numbers
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
>>> numbers = (1,)
>>> (f, rest) = numbers
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Note that `(1)` and `(1, )`are syntactically different, with only the latter being a tuple.

See the *Python Doc* on [Tuples and Sequences](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) for more details.

Comment: Note as of Python 3 you can do `(f, *rest) = range(10)` and you'll get `f == 0` and `rest == [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`. You can also do `f, *rest, last = range(10)` and it will work as expected. See http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/ for details

Comment: Ah, interesting. I mostly code in 2.7.x for a variety of reasons, so had not come across this yet.

Answer (score 3):

```
(f, rest) = numbers
```

**unpacks** the tuple. That is, it takes the two values stored in numbers and stores them in f and rest, respectively. Note that the number of variables you unpack into must be the same as the number of values in the tuple, or else an exception will be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Tupple is a data structure in which you can store multiple items under one name.

Lets say that we have a tupple(t) with two items.

Then t[0] = first_item and t[1] = sencond_item

Another way of accessing the tupple item is:

(f, rest) = numbers

In this syntax numbers (tupple) must have 2 items only otherwise it is an exception

f = numbers[0]
rest = numbers[1]